# How to change the position of groups colors in DimPlot of Seurat

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, ggplot2

I have a Seurat object and plotted the Dimplot for UMAP visualization for 2 variables, as shown in the image below.

[image]

Now, the problem is that I want the group by variables such as `Non-responder and Responder` and `anti-CLTA4, anti-CLTA4+PD1, anti-PD1` on the top of the UMAP plot and not on the right side. My desired output would look like the following.

[image]

The timely help is highly appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: If you plan to export the graph anyway, the easiest way could be to edit it with a vector graphics program. The other option is to save the `ggplot` object returned by `Dimplot()` and modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of Seurat `DimPlot()` to `ggplot` ? @Cloudberry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DimPlot returns a ggplot object, so ggplot functions can be applied to it. You can change the legend position like this:

```
DimPlot(data) + theme(legend.position = "top")
# or
DimPlot(data) + theme(legend.position = c(.1, .9))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, problem solved. I was trying to solve it from DimPlot() method.